# In earlier versions of Matlab, how can I get the posterior probabilities output of SVM?

Tags: matlab, svm, roc, auc

I need to get the posterior probabilities output of trained SVM instead of the binarized output. In the latest versions of Matlab, this can be done by the following steps:

```
SVMModel = fitcsvm(trainingInput,trainingTarget);
SVMModelPosteriorProb = fitSVMPosterior(SVMModel);
[label, probability] = predict(SVMModelPosteriorProb,testInput);
```

However, `fitcsvm` and `fitSVMPosterior` are both introduced in R2014a version and I am using an earlier one. When I pass the output of the `svmtrain` function to the `predict` function, I get an error message stating that `struct` is not the expected argument type.

Is there a way to do this in earlier Matlab versions?